# Website not loading on mobile when its clicked through a bio

Tags: css, mobile, loading

my website loads completely fine on every platform, but when i put it in a bio like Tiktok, Instagram and try and open it on my phone the css does not load just the html, what could the problem be? here is my
https://github.com/bradsviral/joltmgmt
I have already tried relinking all the CSS and I went on cloudflare and turned off and on the CSS toggle in auto minify

Answer (score 0):

It can be because of the integrated browser of instagram and tiktok, open insta or tiktok on chrome and open the link from there and see if that works. And try to open the link after putting it on different social medias like twitter and see if there it works